# Pass function as a prop in react, Cannot read property '_handleEvent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I try to implement a class table in react. A table has multiple rows, each having a button. As a start, I try to pass a function handleEvent.

Now, I always end up with:
TypeError: Cannot read property '_doDeleteItem' of undefined

There is some kind of binding error, but i cannot figure it out.

Cheers

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props,context) {
    super(props,context);
    this.state = { k : 3 };
    this._handleEvent = this._handleEvent.bind(this);
  }

  _handleEvent (e) {
     console.log('delete')
   }

   render() {
      var rows = [];
      var lastCategory = null;
      this.props.results.slice(-this.state.k).forEach(function(r) {
      rows.push( <Rows result = {r} deleteItem = {this._handleEvent} />);
      });
      return(
        <Panel>
         <ListGroup fill>
          {rows}
         </ListGroup>
        </Panel>
      );
     } 
    }
    export default Table;

   class Rows extends Component{
     render() {
      return(
        <ListGroupItem>
          <b>Text:</b><Button onClick = {this.props.deleteItem} type="False"><b>True</b></Button><br/>
        </ListGroupItem>
      );
      }
     }
```

Comment: Show your 'tried' approaches.

Comment: Do you have the code of `RowItem`? That `deleteTrue` is quite weird

Comment: Any time you get a 'cannot do X of undefined' in JavaScript, 100% of the time this means that you are trying to access a property or do something on a variable that has not yet been defined, thus the undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not the component instance inside the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Either use an arrow function, bind the anonymous function, or pass `this` as the second argument to `forEach`:

```
 this.props.results.slice(-this.state.k).forEach(function(r) {
   rows.push( <Rows result = {r} deleteItem = {this._handleEvent} />);
 }.bind(this));
```

or

```
 this.props.results.slice(-this.state.k).forEach(function(r) {
   rows.push( <Rows result = {r} deleteItem = {this._handleEvent} />);
 }, this);
```